# Baire related problem

Tags: real-analysis, baire-category

Let $f:\Bbb R\to \Bbb R$, $f$ in $C^{\infty}$. Suppose that for all $x \in \Bbb R$, there exists an integer $n$ (which depends on $x$) such that

$f^{n}(x) = 0$  ($f^{n}$ is composing $f$ $n$ times)

Prove that there exists a non-empty open set in $\Bbb R$ where $f$ is a polynomial.

My professor told me to use Baire theorem, but I can't see how!

Could you help me, please?

Comment: $f^n$ doesn't the $n$-th derivative of $f$?!

Comment: Are you sure you mean $n$-fold composition, and not $n$th derivative? This reminds me of a result that Ralph Boas has written a lot about, for what it's worth.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very difficult problem, assuming that $f^{(n)}(x)=0$, instead of $f^n(x)=0$.

For a proof see [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/34059/if-f-is-infinitely-differentiable-then-f-coincides-with-a-polynomial).

However, if you further assume that $f$ is real analytical, then it is not hard to show 
that it is a polynomial, using a standard cardinals argument.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean by  $f^n$ the $n$th derivative.

For $n\in \Bbb N$ set $F_n=\{x\in \Bbb R \ \ ,\  f^{(n)}(x)=0\}$.

For each $n$, $F_n$ is a closed subset of $\Bbb R$.

We have $\cup_{n\in \Bbb N}F_n=\Bbb R$, since $\Bbb R$ is complete and the interior of $\cup_{n\in \Bbb N}F_n$ is not empty  , (By Bair Theorem ) there exits $N\in \Bbb N$ such the interior of $F_N$ is not empty , That is $F_N$ contain an open interval $]a,b[$ ($a<b$).

For all $x\in ]a,b[$, $f^{(N)}(x)=0$ hence $f$ is polynomial in $]a,b[$.